# CI Ajax Calling Issue

Tags: php, ajax, continuous-integration

I have controller named "test.php". I have also written the ajax calling functions in this page as well. Like for checking data, uploading the image etc.
Problem is when ever i call any of the ajax function , and do logout after it (successful or UN-sucessfull result of ajax), And then login again, then it transfer me to same ajax function which i called before logging out, instead of index function. Below are steps that i follow.

1. Call ajax function "test/ajax_1_chk" to check user data.
2. Logout the user.
3. login Again with any user.
4. it will redirect to "test/ajax_1_chk" , but instead ti should go to "test/index". this happens only first time.

I applied path in it. But does not work all the time.

Can any one guide me in this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not enough information. It's a problem in your code.

Comment: Then what should i check , both have code to only check the information. And its not with only one function. Every Ajax function used on that page which was called last before doing Logout, is loaded after ay user do the Login Again.